# Theorem constructing a mathematical structure from a set of internal isomorphisms

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, universal-algebra, bibliography

I am searching for information about a specific theorem mentioned in the book "Discriminator-algebras: algebraic representation and model theoretic properties" by Heinrich Werner. The theorem in question is said to provide a way to construct a mathematical structure from a set of functions that satisfy certain conditions and closures, and this structure has precisely those functions as the set of all isomorphisms between all its substructures. I think the theorem is attributed to Stone in the book.

Thank you very much for your attention and assistance!

Comment: Can you give a more precise reference? On what page of this book is the theorem mentioned?

Comment: Also, what is an internal isomorphism in this context?

Comment: Like Alex, I'm not sure what you mean by "internal isomorphism", but perhaps you are talking about the construction which, given a set $X$ and a closed $G\leq \operatorname{Sym}(X)$, yields a structure with universe $X$, whose automorphism group is exactly $G$? In that case, it suffices to add (for each natural $n$) a predicate for each orbit of $G$ in $X^n$.

Comment: By internal isomorphism, I mean an isomorphism between substructures.

Comment: I've never heard an isomorphism between substructures called an internal isomorphism. These are usually called partial isomorphisms, or partial automorphisms, in the case that the domain and codomain are substructures of a single structure. Searching for this keyword indicates that there's a reasonably large literature on "inverse semigroups" and "inverse monoids" which are algebraic structures abstracting partial automorphism monoids. The theorem you're looking for is probably in that literature.

Comment: @AlexKruckman: The phrase 'internal isomorphism' for 'isomorphism between substructures' has a long history. It appears on the first page of  A.F.Pixley, The ternary discriminator function in universal algebra. Math. Ann. 191 (1971), 167-180. This is probably not the first use of it. On the other hand, 'partial isomorphism' typically means something different than 'isomorphism between substructures'.

Comment: @KeithKearnes That's good to know, thanks for the reference. I didn't mean to suggest the terminology hadn't been used, just that I hadn't heard it. I'm curious about the other meaning of "partial isomorphism". Are you referring to the back-and-forth notion? I've seen people define structure to be "partially isomorphic" if there is a back-and-forth system between them, but define a "partial isomorphism" to be a single isomorphism between substructures - so e.g. the maps in the back-and-forth system are partial isomorphisms. (This is not ideal terminology!)

Comment: @AlexKruckman: I meant that a 'partial isomorphism' is often defined to be a certain kind of partial function $f\colon M\to N$ between *different* structures. Also, the domain and codomain are often taken to be subsets rather than substructures.